# On which processor(s) do my simulations run?

Tags: macos, terminal, multi-core

I am currently running 11 numerical simulations (coded in `C`) on another Mac computer via my Terminal using `ssh` and `screen` (Bash) on Mac OS.

The computer that is running the 11 processes has 16 processors. At first sight, it seems to me that the simulations are slower when I run several of them in the same time as if only one processor was used to run all 11 simulations. **Is it possible? How can I tell which simulation/process is ran on which processor?**

Comment: Check if your simulations are synchronizing access to a shared resource (whether purposefully or not). If you're sure the simulations *should* scale, it may be that somewhere in the code there are calls to library/OS functions that don't scale well.

Comment: I don't have so much knowledge in computer science. What does "are synchronizing access to a shared resource" mean? What should I do to check that? The code uses extensively GNU Scientific Library. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's a big topic, synchronization. Simply put, if 11 apps need to access a single resource, and that resource doesn't allow concurrent access, then only one out of the 11 apps can access the resource at a time. The others have to wait. The concept of locking a resource and blocking other apps/threads from using it is often referred to as synchronization.

Comment: Hmmm, if it's not a sync issue, it might be the way you're launching your simulations. Check this out: https://files.nyu.edu/mg152/public/R_on_multiple_cores.html

Comment: @misha256 I opened only one screen (after `ssh`) but I made 11 "state" for this screen (using Ctrl-a + c). Might it be in cause? Should I have better to open several screens and call the executable independently in each screen?

Comment: Definitely try it, as per the R instructions. I wish I knew for sure but I am 90% a Windows user so my experience here is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't know!

The a bit longer answer is: The OS (any end user OS actually) schedules the processes itself and assigns it to CPUs. Even when running only the simulation the processes might get interrupted and a very short time later continued on the same or another CPU.

There is most probably an even longer answer (including code to assign processes to CPUs, thoughts about what could impact parallization and performance etc.) but that's beyond the scope of AskDifferent. Asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) might get better results for this.

Comment: You definitively will get better answers on that on SU or SO :-)

Comment: Ah, and if it get's closed on SU, just flag your question here and we can migrate it over to them.

Comment: Sure you can know; the described bevbaior points to the fact the simulator exe is singled threaded this means it would finish in the same amount of time on a 3.0Ghz single core or 3.0 Ghz 12 core processor provided everything else was indent oval